# Alphabet soup problem with best time complexity that is possible

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I got the below problem (alphabet soup) as my data structure course exercise.

https://github.com/kennedyCzar/AlphabetSoup-Using-Django

I solved it in O(m+s) where m is the length of the message and s is the length of the soup (I just created a table from the soup and decided if the message can be created or not using that table)

```
def checkBowl(message, soup):
  d = {}

  # O(S)
  for c in soup:
    d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1

  # O(m)
  for c in message:
    if(d.get(c, 0) == 0):
      return False
    else:
      d[c] -= 1

  # So the overall time complexity is O(m+s)
  return True
```

but it seems the given GitHub solved it in O(mlogm) however I think his/her solution is in O(m*s) cause he/she just didn't consider python's in operator works in O(length of the list).

By the way can someone please hint, is that possible to solve this problem with a better time complexity? (the problem specified that the bowl of soup may be very large)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, the linked algorithm, for each letter in the message, iterates over the soup to find the letter. If the letter is found, then it is removed from the soup. Hence the time complexity is `O(m * S)`.

Your algorithm is `O(m + S)` because you iterate only once over the soup. So your solution is better.

But what if the soup is very large? What about an infinite soup? If the soup is an infinite generator, you will never finish to build your dictionary even if the first letters of the soup are the message itself.

This leads to an idea: why not iterate over the letters of the soup until you get the letters of the message? In this case, you'll read letters until you are able to write the message and stop as soon as the message is complete:

```
import collections

def check_bowl2(message, soup):
    # O(m)
    message_letters = collections.Counter(message)

    # O(S)
    for c in soup:
        if c not in message_letters: # we don't need `c`
            pass
        elif message_letters[c] == 1:
            del message_letters[c] # we won't need `c` anymore
            if not message_letters: # we found all letters
                return True
        else: # we still need `c`, but one less time
            message_letters[c] -= 1

    return False
```

The time complexity is still `O(m + S)`, but the space complexity is reduced: `O(m)` versus `O(S)`. Of course, if you are looking for many messages in the same soup, building the dict is still the best option.

I don't think you'll find an algorithm faster than `O(S)`: in the worst case (the message is absent), you have to iterate over the whole soup at least once.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned the question says "It may be a very large bowl of soup containing many letters" and your solution somehow solves that. but is accessing dictionary O(1) or O(n) in the worst case? I mean as @TUI lover mentioned worst case is O(n) so the complexity would be O(mS), right?

Comment: As @TUI lover stated, the worst case is `O(n)` for a dictionary. But in your case, you can assume that there is no collision between characters `hash`es. CPython3.8.5 on Ubuntu: ```>>> import string [LF]
>>> len(set(hash(c) for c in string.printable)) == len(string.printable) [LF]
True```. If you know the set of keys, you can always create a hash function with no collision (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can go below linear with this problem, as it is not possible to check if a letter belongs to the alphabet soup without parsing it, and you obviously must parse your message.

BUT, your solution is only linear on AVERAGE as hash maps have a constant complexity on average only. So your worst case complexity is more like O(s^2+s.m).

You can improve it using your own data struct that do not rely on hash but binary trees for example, to achieve a worst case complexity of O(s.log(s)+ m.log(s)).

Edit : you also can exploit the fact that your characters are only ASCII ones.

```
def checkBowl(message, soup):                                                                                                                                                                            
  d = [0 for i in range(128)]
              
  # O(S)      
  for c in soup:
    d[ord(c)] +=1
              
  # O(m)      
  for c in message:
    if(d[ord(c)] == 0):
      return False
    else:     
      d[ord(c)] -= 1
               
  # So the overall time complexity is O(m+s)
  return True
```

Comment: Oh, right. I completely forgot that hash table's complexity in the worst case is O(n). Thanks :)

Comment: But by using heap which is a complete binary tree the order would be O(s.log(s)+m.log(m)), not O(s.log(s)+m.log(s)). Am I right? I mean you made a typo in the last line of your answer or I misunderstand the solution using a binary tree.

Comment: @Me. I was thinking about a solution where the only difference with your current solution is the map implementation, using a tree over hash. What is your idea of a solution?

Comment: @Me. Do you know the topology of the alphabet from which the alphabet soup is generated? I have a truly linear solution if you know which character you may encounter

Comment: I mean, I just saw an implementation of a simple map in K&R2 a long time ago which was based on hashing. I have to search about implementing maps using trees. 
Anyway if, first we sort both soap and message using heapsort and then set two pointers pointing at the first character of soup and message respectively and by using them decide if we can create the message or not the solution would be in O(s.log(s)+m.log(s)).

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no example of message or alphabet but from other solutions which I saw yet, message and alphabet can consist even punctuation marks, numbers and ...

Comment: What I mean is, are letters from alphabet ASCII characters?

Comment: Yeah, I think we can assume that alphabet letters are ASCII. I would appreciate it if you edit your answer and add your new idea too.

Comment: I do it as soon as possible

Comment: Ah, right, actually as @jferard mentioned we can also make sure that there is no collision between characters' hashes and still use the dictionary with O(1). Thank you, I really appreciate you.